# Is it possible to deploy JS files over EC2 instance using AWS CodeDeploy

Tags: bitbucket, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to figure-out the right way to deploy my code from bitbucket to AWS EC2 instance.

Earlier, I was using git clone by having git installed on the EC2 instance and adding that as remote and pushing code to that but this time I am trying to explore codedeploy but I have not seen any documentation which can help me do deploy my code on a particular directory in my EC2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to your question is Yes, CodeDeploy can help you deploy your code to EC2 in your specified directory.

In CodeDeploy, you can specify the source and destination of a deployment: source means where the file is located in the repo/S3, and destination is the final directory on the instance that the file will be deployed. This part is managed by a config-like file called AppSpec file, see here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/app-spec-ref.html for details.

General overview of CodeDeploy is here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/welcome.html

Hope this helps.